# vancouver.bst : How to remove the dot after the journal name

Tags: bibtex, natbib, punctuation

I need to remove the dots after the names of the journals in the references of my paper. I am using the `vancouver` style file.

My minimum working example (MWE) looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[comma, super]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{baum2014,
Author = {Baum, KT and Desai, A and Field, J and Miller, LE and Rausch, J and Beebe, DW},
Journal = {J Child Psychol Psychiatry},
Number = {2},
Pages = {180--190},
Title = {Sleep restriction worsens mood and emotion regulation in adolescents},
Year = {2014}}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

And here, I am citing the article \cite{baum2014}.

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\bibliography{my_bibliography}

\end{document}
```

My output looks like this:

[image]

I want to get rid of the dot after the journal name.

I think, I can do this by modifying the `vancouver.bst` file. However, I am not very familiar with the style file codes. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have just edited my entry by adding one.

Comment: @lyolya: `vancouver1.bst` or `vancouver.bst`?

Comment: @Werner: I copied and renamed the file to introduce modifications and not mess with the original file.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this same problem and couldn't find the modifications mentioned in the comments above, so I'm posting the solution that I eventually arrived at after some trial and error.

Here's the original code block from `vancouver.bst` being modified:

```
% urlbst
FUNCTION {output.nonnull.original}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ". " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
```

I replaced the second `add.period$` with `add.blank`, and then moved the declaration of `add.blank` up from its original location at lines 251-253 to precede this function.  The final version looks like this:

```
FUNCTION {add.blank}  % moved up from below
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

% urlbst
FUNCTION {output.nonnull.original}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ". " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.blank " " * write$ }  % replaced add.period$
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
```

Comment: Welcome, remember not to modify the original file, but a copy with a different name. And the changes clearly marked within the file.

Comment: Edited above to mark changes. I did make a copy with a different name as per license, thanks.